# How to align form at the center of the page in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css. i am trying to build up my own form and i am trying to align it in the center. I used the align property in css but its not working.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Web Page Having A Form</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create a New Account</h1>
      <form >
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Name :</td> <td><input type="text" name="name"></td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Email :</td> <td><input type="text" name="email"></td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Password :</td> <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Confirm Password :</td> <td><input type="password" name="cpwd"><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
</body>
```

Css Code:

```
    body
{
    background-color : #484848;
}
h1
{
    color : #000000;
    text-align : center;
    font-family: "SIMPSON";
}
form
{
    align:"center";
}
```

How should i change my code to align the entire form in the center?

Comment: did you want horizontal centering or vertical?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HwUB5/2/)**

**css**

```
    body {
    background-color : #484848;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    color : #000000;
    text-align : center;
    font-family: "SIMPSON";
}
form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked, Can you please also tell me why the width is needed?

Comment: Can you please explain why that `width` property is needed?

Answer (score 8):

This is my answer. I'm not a Pro. I hope this answer may help you :3

```
<div align="center">
<form>
.
.
Your elements
.
.
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `<form>` element inside a `div` container and apply css to the `div` instead which makes things easier.

```css
#aDiv{width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div id="aDiv">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="name">
            </td>
            <br>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Email :</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="email">
            </td>
            <br>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="pwd">
            </td>
            <br>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password :</td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="cpwd">
              <br>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use table and not the form. Its done by using margin.

```
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

also try using something like

```
table td {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

instead of `<br />`

and also your input should end with `/>`
e.g:

```
<input type="password" name="cpwd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use the `<center></center>` tags.

Comment: try margin: 0 auto; on a container div for the form.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap the  element inside a div container as a row like 
   your form here or something like that.
2. Set css attribute:

   - width: 30%; (or anything you want)
   - margin: auto;
     Please take a look on following picture for more detail.[image]