# How to align bootstrap form at the center of the web page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap styling for form. I want this form to be displayed at the center of the page but I'm not able to do it even though I tried `margin 0 auto` [in css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089042/7004388). Can anyone help.

This is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <br>
  <form class="form-horizontal inputForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name &nbsp</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email &nbsp</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of my browser displaying the above form:

> [image]

Comment: Do you need it centered only horizontally, or vertically as well?

Comment: @m.spyratos want the form at the center of the page horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I've wrapped the form with

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.mx-auto centers the column automatically and inside the column you can add your form that has .col-3 and col-9, in my example. But adjust it according to how you need the label and input to be shown.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGLKXw).

**Edit:** I've realized you're using Bootstrap 3, not 4. In that case, you can try something like this, but it needs a bit of work on mobile. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPqKyW).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to center `body`, put the form in a div and center that div.

```css
body { text-align: center; border: 1px solid;}
form { margin: auto; width: 200px; border: solid blue; display: block;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <br>
  <form class="form-horizontal inputForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name &nbsp</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email &nbsp</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But now it is showing me [in this way](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/bootstrap-form/blob/master/ss-2.PNG) @jack

Comment: text-align center also the form

Comment: You need to reproduce the problem in here, not in an image. Use jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: When the screen size is less it is showing me your output. But when I maximize the window to full screen, the form input is not rendered properly. 
Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavanchilukuri/ayfr7rcn/) @jack

Comment: It is because the inner form elements use `float: left`. Add this. `.form-group *{float: none;}`. You probably need also other fixing. Good luck.